# How to show alert and refresh the current page through controller using formmethod.post method in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a feedback form by FormMethod.Post method in mvc. Now, in my form data is saving but after save the data page is refreshed so that user cant know that data is successfully inserted or not. So, for thats why I want to alert the javascript and refresh the current page.

I have done many things but didnt work anything.

So, let I am showing you the last thing I tried that in this code.

Here is my view

```
<script>
@ViewBag.scripCall

    function Callback() {
        alert("Callback function is working");
    }
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "FeedBack", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{   
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="~/images/default.png" style="margin:10px" height="200" width="200" id="imagePreview" />
                <input type="file" name="ImageUpload" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" id="ImageUpload"
                    onchange="ShowImagePreview(this, document.getElementById('imagePreview'))" class="control-label" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName, new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FullName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter The Name" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <br />
                </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Occupation, new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.DropDownList("Occupation", ViewData["occupationList"] as SelectList, new {@class="control-label", style="width:250px;" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <br />
                </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserFeedBack, new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserFeedBack, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter FeedBack", style="height:250px;" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="submit" id="btn_save" class="button" value="Save" />
                </div>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
          <span class="control-label" style="color:red">Note : Please do not upload <b>DSLR photo</b>. It does not support. Thank You...!!!</span>
          </div>
    </div>   
}
```

Here is my controller

```
public ActionResult Create(FeedBackViewModel feedbackViewModel)
{
    try
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["ImageUpload"];
        if (file != null)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(feedbackViewModel.ImageUpload.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(feedbackViewModel.ImageUpload.FileName);
            fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
            feedbackViewModel.ImageUpload.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/"), fileName));
        }

        ContentRepository service = new ContentRepository();
        int i = service.CreateFeedBack(file, feedbackViewModel);
        if (i == 1)
        {
            ViewBag.scripCall = "Callback();";
            return View();

            //return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Thanks for Feedback!');</script>");    
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Sorry, Something went wrong. Please Try Again...!!!');</script>");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View();//"Error", new HandleErrorInfo(ex, "StaffRegistration", "Create"));
    }
}
```

Now, in this code the latest thing I triedto show the alert by @ViewBag.scripCall and also the refresh the current page but it also not working.

Thank You.

Comment: You could store the value of `ViewBag.scripCall` into an hidden field and on `DOMContentLoaded` check that field and do whatever you want. Btw. If you do not need a full page reload, better use Ajax.

Comment: Why are you returning the view. You should be redirecting if successful. And you do not necessarily need a message (by default the user knows its successful if it redirects. But you can always add a message to `TempData` and read it in the GET method and then display it in the view

Comment: I used TempData but in tempdata it shows error. @StephenMuecke

Comment: I know but then also I want to show the message and also refresh the page is there any thing that I can do. @StephenMuecke

Comment: Well that would be because your code is wrong (we cannot guess what it was). but again, why in the world are you returning the view if it was successfully saved - are you expecting the user to edit it again? Redirect to another page if the save was successful

Comment: I dont think so that my code is wrong because it is inserted properly and many of the functionality working properly. If my code is wrong then you have the pleasure to me. :) And also thank you for giving me suggestion for redirect to another page. I will do that.

Comment: You stated that you use of `TempData` was not working but there is nothing in your question about `TempData` :)

Comment: as per I describe in question previously that I tried many thing in that many thing this tempdata also come. If I write in question about I try then the question is too lenthy and also it can be said most of the user didnt understand that question. So thats why I didnt describe tempdata in question.